# CSS deeply nested :last-child selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am working with some html components and I basically want to set a `:last-child selector` on a specific class. The issue is that the class is deeply nested within the parent class that I want to use the selector on so when I use last child it is affecting the css for all of the components. One of the issues I am running into is that the selctor I want to change the css for is nested in different components.

Here is an example of what I tried:

```css
parent .my-class:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```css
parent > * > .my-class:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```html
<parent>
  <a>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
  </a>
  <b>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
  </b>
  <c>
    <div class="my-class"><div>
  </c>
  <d>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
  </d>
</parent>
... more parents with more children elements that can be whatever and nest more .my-class elements
```

What is happening wiht my css is that they are all being recognized as the :last-child. What I want to happen is only the full selector `parent > d > .my-class` to be recognized as the last child.

Keep in mind that the elements are not always in the same order so using the selector I provided above will not work for my case.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/timsexperiments/pen/WNgjLpB?editors=1100) exmple.

Comment: Are your a, b, c, and d elements representing something else, or is that your actual code?

Comment: Those are just representing any differing element, but it shouldn't matter even if that was the actual code.

Checkout the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/timsexperiments/pen/WNgjLpB?editors=1100) for an actual example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was putting the `:last-child` selector on the wrong element in the selector. The correct selector should be:

```css
parent > *:last-child .my-class {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

The [codepen](https://codepen.io/timsexperiments/pen/WNgjLpB?editors=1100) has been updated with the correct css needed to make it work.